# How can I analyze what causes continous disk access in my Synology NAS?

Tags: linux, nas, synology

Since some days (no update of any app or os was done) my NAS operates day and night with disk access. In the processes panel, I cannot see something that reveals much:

[image]

Somebody knows how I can analyse which process accesses the disc?

(Maybe every Linux user can help this, I am a casual nix user.)

Comment: Searched for [linux which process accessing the disk](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linux+which+process+accessing+the+disk&t=lm)?

Comment: looks like a good start, thx

Comment: Maybe you have any unexpected network-traffic, which causes read/writes. You can try to check the traffic (to your NAS) with WireShark.